# Difference between weak and strong convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence, weak-topology, strong-convergence

I don't really understand the difference between *weak convergence* and *strong convergence* of operators.

According to my script, strong convergence of a bounded operators $A_n,A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ means:

$A_n x \rightarrow Ax$ for all $x \in H$.

And weak convergence means:

$<y,A_n x> \ \rightarrow  \ <y,A x>$ for all $x,y \in H$.

Strong convergence clearly implies weak convergence. But i don't understand why weak convergence doesn't imply strong convergence.

If we have

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}<y,A_n x>=<y,Ax>$,

we can pull the limit inside the scalar product to obtain:

$<x,\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n y>=<y,Ax>$.

Since this is true for all $x,y \in H$ we obtain strong convergence. Where is the mistake in here?

Comment: To "pull the limit inside" we first have to know that $\lim A_nx$ exists.

Comment: In Hilbert space $l^2$, let $A_n$ be the right shift by $n$.  $$(a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots) \mapsto (0,0,\dots,0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots)$$where $n$ zeros are inserted at the beginning.  Show $A_n \to O$ in the weak operator topolopgy, but not in the strong operator topology.  Using this example, you can find an error in your proof.

Comment: `\langle,\rangle` renders the angled braces $\langle a,b\rangle$